# How we can publish flutter app on app store from windows

Tags: flutter, app-store, flutter-ios-build

I Develop a flutter application, I am a Windows user. I don't have a MacBook, so is there any way to publish the flutter app on the app store using windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** build or publish iOS from Windows or any other system except MacOS. If you have no mac take a look at cloud services that can dedicate one to you (e.g. [MacStadium](https://www.macstadium.com)). CI/CD services like [CodeMagic](https://codemagic.io), [AppCenter](https://appcenter.ms) is an option too, it is more suitable for small or pet projects when you don't need to build iOS often.